# Get load time of a frame

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I have the following sample HTML:

```
<body>
<script>
   function print(){
    Number(window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart);
   }
</script>
<frame src="myPAGE.html" onload="print()"/>
</body>
```

When I run in the Chrome's console:

```
Number(window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart);
```

It always gives me the same result, no matter what page I open in the `frame` object (set by choosing in the UI, ommited in the snippet for simplification). This is because `window` is referring to the "outer" `document`. However, both Chrome and IE, in their debugger, allow me to change the target window, and therefore making this code run successfully.
How can I do this in Javascript, however?

Comment: I didn't manage to get it to work but if you give your frame an id, you should be able to call the window object of that frame using `window.top.frames["myframeid"]` (instead of `window`)

Comment: Feel free to answer the topic with that solution so that I can mark it as Solved. That was exactly it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your frame an id, you should be able to call the window object of that frame using `window.top.frames["myframeid"]`.